# Непонятна постановка запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Само предложение: "Однако Шекспир сделал ставку на другой формат тиражирования собственных произведений — сценические показы, и не прогадал".

Не могу понять, почему перед союзом *и* ставится запятая. Предложение из текста на сайте газеты "Культура".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь имеет место *присоединительная конструкция*, которая дополняет сообщение о действиях субъекта оценочным суждением о них же. Такие конструкции отделяются запятой.

У Розенталя на этот случай есть такой пример:

> Но я не стал возражать, и хорошо сделал...

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120